# Change one attribute value Yii2 REST API

Tags: rest, yii2, yii2-model

I have created a REST API in Yii2 using `ActiveController`. The default implementation of `actionIndex` return all the models. 
What i want to do is to change the value of one attribute before sending response. 
for example i have image uploaded with just its name stored in database.
Before sending a response i want to embed the base URL with image name.
Do i need to override the whole index method or  i can manipulate the single attribute in `action` method?

Comment: overriding the action is what will be the solution in your case as you want to modify the data also

Comment: modify the value in action before sending response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is override the `fields()` method in your model. Lets say you have your ActiveController configured for a model called `YourFile`. If you add the following function to the `YourFile` model the full url can be added for every model in the response:

```
public function fields() {
    return [
        'id',
        'name' => function() {
            return Url::base(true) . $this->name;
        }
    ]
}
```

If you add it like this, it does mean that every code calling `toArray()` on your model will get this result. If you only want it to happen for the `ActiveController` you might want to extend the `YourFile` model and include the `fields()` method only there, so you can configure the `ActiveController` with the extended version.

Answer (score 1):

We can also change the display name of certain fields:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements  \yii\web\IdentityInterface {    
/**     * API safe fields     */    
public function fields()    {

    return [            
        'id',            
        'email_address' => 'email',            
        'first_name',            
        'last_name',            
        'full_name' => function($model) {                
            return $model->getFullName();            
        },            
        'updated_at',            
        'created_at'        
    ];    
}
```

}

see full tutorial here:
http://p2code.com/post/configuring-activecontroller-display-fields-yii-2-21